# Which graphic novel actually contains the events of how Deadpool became Deadpool?

Tags: marvel, deadpool

What is the origin of Deadpool? I know there is a chronological order on here but can anyone tell me which graphic novel contains Deadpool's origin, ie Weapon X to Wolverine, and how he actually became Deadpool?

Answer (score 8):

An inspection of Deadpool's entry in the [Marvel Universe Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Deadpool_(Wade_Wilson)) lists the following under the *Origin* section:

- [Deadpool #-1](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/8462/deadpool_1997_1)
- [Marvel Comics 1998 Annual Starring Deadpool and Death](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000ULPWAC) *only $216.28 on amazon :D*
- [Deadpool #33](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/8488/deadpool_1997_33)

#### But the most recent incarnation of his origin story would be [X-Men Origins: Deadpool](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/28983/x-men_origins_deadpool_2010_1)

> You may have heard there’s a Deadpool movie in the works. Anyway, Wade Wilson’s heard the same thing — and he’s determined to tell his own story before Hollywood screws it up.
>
> Deadpool even hires his own screenwriter, who manages to get the Merc With a Mouth to open up like never before — **revealing not only his origin story, but shocking details you’ve never heard before. We’re talking Oscar™ - worthy stuff here, people.**
>
> That is, unless Hollywood manages to screw it up anyway… One-Shot/Parental Advisory

[image]

Comment: I can't help but think this it one big ad. If you had less rep than me, I'd downvote.

Comment: @MrLister yeah it kinda has that feeling about it alright... but if Marvel want to send me money, I'd be ok with that.

Comment: @Daft Are you sure this is the ONLY origin story? I don't have exact volumes, but I am pretty sure I read the origin story in one of the first collections of `Deadpool Classics`, which collects comics from way before 2010...? Or is this one just some rewrite of the same story, but newer imagery?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka nope.

Comment: @Daft To which one of my questions? :-D

Comment: @FlorianPeschka sorry - _Are you sure this is the ONLY origin story?_ Nope. And to the rest: I don't know.

Answer (score 8):

Just adding this as another answer, event though it may not be entirely what you want.

The first ocurrence of his origins that I could find in my collection was in [Deadpool #18 (1998)](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool_and_Death_Annual_Vol_1_1998)

[image: Deadpool and Death - Deadpool #18 (1998)]

In there, the origin is told as a flashback while Deadpool has some quite interesting interactions with Death.

There, his "origin" is shown as to how he joins the Weapon X program, why he is called *Deadpool*... the whole sherbang

[image: Sample Scene]

## OT Sidenote

The Comic is part of [Deadpool Classic #4](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Deadpool_Classic_Vol_1_4).

[image: Deadpool Classic #4]

The whole story arc from Deadpool #1 on, collected in the first couple of Deadpool Classic volumes is IMHO an extremely well written story, so I highly recommend the whole thing for anyone starting out on Deadpool.

Comment: Anyone like to comment on why this was downvoted 2 times?

Comment: My answer got one too, it just happens sometimes.